# system.net.webexception : Remote name could not be resolved

Tags: .net

in my code at line ResponseStream = Response.GetResponseStream(); i am getting an error remote name could not be resolved : . I searched and found that it is a proxy issue and we need to make some changes but I am unable to figure out as what to do to resolve this . I am hitting a webdev server on https.

Answer (score 0):

Update you web.config/app.config with your proxy setting as below.

```
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy
          usesystemdefault="False"
          bypassonlocal="True" 
          proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888"              
          />
</defaultProxy>
```

Changer the proxyaddress to your actual proxy address